# security constraints using web.xml jsp outside web-inf

Tags: java, web.xml, security-constraint

I have read most of the links which have helped me with the syntax for the security constraints, but somehow it does not work for me.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>No_Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>all_access</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/urls.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/noentry.jsp</url-pattern>
    <auth-constraint/>
</web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```